# Best way to require Haml on Rails3 engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails3 engine application, and I want to use Haml for the views.

First, what I have done was to add this to the engine Gemfile:

```
gem "haml"
```

While I was testing my engine, it was working OK (I have used https://github.com/josevalim/enginex to generate the gem and test it with the dummy application).

My problems started when I tried to use the engine on a real Rails application. The application does not have gem "haml" on it's own Gemfile, and so it was not initializing Haml, so I was receiving template not found errors as it was not looking for the .haml views. I was thinking that by requiring Haml on the Engine it would be enought for it to be also required by the Rails application.

What I have done for now was to add a config/initializers/haml.rb on the engine with this code:

```
require 'haml'
Haml.init_rails(binding)
```

It's working now, but I'm wondering if this is really a good way to do it.
Why Rails is not calling Haml "init.rb" file and so initializing Haml correctly by just adding gem "haml" to the engine Gemfile?

Answer (score 20):

Two things are necessary. First, in the .gemspec:

```
s.add_dependency 'haml', ['>= 3.0.0']
```

And in your lib/gem_name.rb:

```
require 'haml'
```

And then run `bundle` both inside the gem and app directories.

Comment: I realize you answered this many months after the original question, but googling around for various permutations of "rails engine can't see haml" I couldn't find what I was doing wrong.  All I needed was that `require 'haml'` piece, which I figured it would do automatically since my gemspec is using 'haml-rails' in the dependency.  Many thanks for that!

Comment: Can I suggest you add the require to `my_engine/application_controller.rb` since that is where is is used.

Comment: @Kris not all gem engines have `ApplicationController`, so I'm not sure what you would need that.

Comment: I was making the assumption that if you are rendering HTML you are doing so from a controller.

Comment: A gem can only contain a collection of partials, without any controllers. Many different uses and configurations can be thought of.

Comment: Sure, in that case the advice is not applicable.

Answer (score 6):

I think you will have to put haml in the engine gemspec as a dependency in order for bundler to install haml in the target application (and show up in its Gemfile.lock).  Something like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.add_dependency(%q<haml>, [">= 0"])
end
```

I just tested this out on one of my engines.  Without the dependency in the .gemspec it did not install haml in the target app (did not appear in Gemfile.lock).  After I added haml to the gemspec as a dependency, it does show up:

```
PATH
  remote: /rails_plugins/mine/my_engine
  specs:
    my_engine (0.0.0)
      formtastic
      haml
      inherited_resources
      settingslogic
      sqlite3-ruby

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    #................
    haml (3.0.25)
    #................
```

If you are using jeweler, it will add the dependencies to the gemspec automatically based on what is in your Gemfile.. it even adds a developement_dependency if you have the group defined in your Gemfile.  I have only looked at enginex briefly, so I don't know if it has a similar rake task to build the gemspec.

This might help clarify some things:

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Comment: This helped. It was also necessary to be sure to include "require 'haml'" somewhere in the engine.

Comment: yep, I guess I left that out.  I usually add it to the main ruby file.  For my_plugin, it would go at the top of my_plugin/lib/my_plugin.rb