# Haml in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rails-engines

I am developing Rails engine that uses HAML for views templates. So my gemspec has following: line

```
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'haml', ">= 3.0.18"
```

But when I use this gem in an application that does not use HAMl itself, HAML does not seem to be initialized (though Gemfile.lock clearly states that it is in dependencies).

Should I add some HAML initialization in the engine code ?

Comment: Related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015297/best-way-to-require-haml-on-rails3-engines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue. Fixed by requiring haml in **engine.rb**

```
require 'haml'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can declare a standard gem dependency by putting your own gem requirement in the init.rb for your engine:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem 'haml', :version => 'haml'    
end
```