# How to use SASS, HAML, and CoffeeScript in Rails 3.2.x Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

Currently, I have a Rails 3.2.9 Engine which is using `sass-rails`. When I generate a controller with a couple actions, the assets are also generated (i.e., javascript and CSS). However, both the Javascript and SASS are `*.js` and `*.css` files. They're not CoffeeScript (`*.js.coffee`) or SASS (`*.css.sass`). Any ideas how to get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different solution which will use the `coffee-rails` and `sass-rails` gems by default - also fixes `haml-rails`.

I added this to the top of my `engine.rb` file:

```
require 'rails'
require 'coffee-rails'
require 'sass/rails'
require 'haml-rails'
```

What I did was inspect the source code of these files to see how they work in a normal Rails application. For example, in `haml-rails` I looked at [`lib/haml-rails.rb`](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/blob/master/lib/haml-rails.rb) and saw the following:

```
require 'haml'
require 'rails'

module Haml
  module Rails
    class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
      if ::Rails.version.to_f >= 3.1
        config.app_generators.template_engine :haml
      else
        config.generators.template_engine :haml
      end
    ...
```

Similar files exist for `sass-rails` ([`lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/master/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb)) and `coffee-rails` ([`lib/coffee/rails/engine.rb`](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/blob/master/lib/coffee/rails/engine.rb)).

Answer (score 2):

Just append `--stylesheet_engine=sass --javascript_engine=coffee` to your generator command (I'm assuming `rails g controller`).

Comment: Why isn't this being used by default?