# Use Haml in rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, haml

I have made a mountable plugin using haml as template. I have added haml and haml-rails in my gemspec.

I use it in a project, I add it in my Gemfile as follows:

**gem 'my_plugin', :git=> "git@github.com:lishoubo/my_plugin.git"**

after execute bundle install, I see the haml and haml-rails have been installed.

But when I start the server, It prompts error:

**Missing template**

It seems the the project can not load haml gem event it install them. I guess it because the haml gems are installed for plugin not for the project. So I add haml and haml-rails to project Gemfile. It dose work.

However, I do not think it needs to add haml gem "again" to project Gemfile. Because I use a plugin, and this plugin uses haml, why I should add it to my Gemfile?

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I guess your generators aren't generating your views. Have you added the config.generator block in config/application.rb?

Comment: yes, I add both in my plugin and the project

Comment: I found another solution here.http://stackoverflow.com/a/6938720/1892043

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to require Haml on Rails3 engines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015297/best-way-to-require-haml-on-rails3-engines)